# Edit Worldspace UI layer?

Tags: sorting, unity-game-engine, user-interface, rendering

I need to have my worldspace UI render over my ceiling layer; however, there's no way to edit the render layer for the object. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the `Sorting Layer` option in the `Canvas` component:

[image: Canvas]

You can create a custom layer which renders on top of everything else like so:

[image: Tags and layers panel]

Comment: This does not work. My UI is still clipping in the sprite below. How does the layer affect the rendering process without any other changes?